# Hacer que método actue sobre resultado de método

Tags: php, poo

Hola a todos les pido ayuda ya que estoy intentado hacer que una función de un objeto actue sobre el resultado de otra función, para explicarme mejor aquí hay un ejemplo de lo que quiero hacer:

```
Class objeto
{
  public function hola()
  {
    return "Hola"
  }

}

$object = new objeto()
```

Ahora lo que me gustaría hacer es por ejemplo crear una función la cual se vea algo así:

```
$object->hola()->saludo()
```

Lo que busco es que una función en este caso, saludo, actue en base a lo que devuelva otra función por ejemplo que en este caso saludo devuelva el resultado de hola, ¿o solo tal y como esta el código esta bien?, no pude encontrar mucha información sobre esto en internet así que me gustaría que me ayudaran ya que soy "nuevo" en la programación orientada a objetos. Desde ya gracias :)

### Edit

Hice este edit debido a que estoy teniendo problemas, por lo que mejor voy a dar mi caso en específico, lo que quiero hacer es hacer lo que hace un orm, en este caso quiero hacer que un `where` no regrese nada, pero si agrego un método por ejemplo un método llamado `all` me gustaría que me regrese todos los resultados que el `where` principalmente devolvio, esto lo estoy haciendo algo así:

```
class orm extends Db
{

private $last_result;



public function where(id)
{

    $this->last_result = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $id")->fetch_object();
}

public function all()
{

    return $this->last_result;
}

}
```

Ahora mi pregunta es ¿cómo puedo llamar a estos metodos juntos? de forma que se vea así:

```
$objeto->where(1)->all()
```

Si lo hago así me da este error:

```
Expected type 'object'. Found 'void'
```

Me imagino que es porque estoy haciendo algo mal. Otra vez desde ya gracias

Comment: @Triby ok, mejor la voy a editar agregando mi caso en específico ya que estoy teniendo problemas otra vez

Comment: @Triby listo ya actualicé mi pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero es que vas a necesitar una instancia para cada tabla, de forma que realmente te pueda ser útil y, recuerda, para encadenar métodos, se debe devolver la instancia.

**Importante:** Ten en cuenta que esto es un ejemplo de lo que quieres hacer, suponiendo que usas PDO; pero no es recomendable ejecutar consultas integrando directamente los valores, investiga sobre consultas preparadas.

```
class orm extends Db {
    private $_table;
    private $_query;
    private $_stmt;

    // Especificar la tabla que se va a manejar en esta clase
    public function __construct($table) {
        $this->_table = $table;
    }
    // Crea un método para iniciar la consulta
    public function queryFields($fields = '*') {
        $this->_query = "SELECT $fields FROM {$this->_table}";
        // Devolver instancia para poder encadenar
        return $this;
    }
    // Crea un método para agregar filtro por ID
    public function whereId($id) {
        $this->_query .= " WHERE id = $id";
        return $this;
    }
    // Crea un método para ejecutar la consulta
    public function exec() {
        // Prepara la consulta
        $this->_stmt = $this->prepare($this->_query);
        // Ejecuta
        $this->_stmt->execute();
        return $this;
    }
    // Un método para leer y devolver todas las filas
    public function getAll() {
        return $this->_stmt->fetchAll();
    }
}
```

Ahora puedes encadenar los métodos:

```
// Instanciar la clase
$tb = new orm('usuarios');
// Puedes especificar las columnas que deseas leer
$userRow = $tb->queryFields('id, name, email')
    // Filtrar por ID
    ->whereId(5)
    // Ejecutar consulta
    ->exec()
    // Finalmente, obtener datos y asignarlos a $userRow
    ->getAll();
```

**Notas finales:** Como puedes ver, cada método va actualizando propiedades de la clase y el siguiente las toma para realizar otras tareas. Por supuesto, **es necesario validar cada paso** para evitar errores y debo insistir en que **uses consultas preparadas adecuadamente**, esto fue solo un ejemplo rápido.

Comment: muchas gracias, así ya funcionó